# SQL query for complex IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i have a table that i want to short by ID.The IDs that i use are a bit complex. The form of the IDs is

> EM_{A-Z}{INT}

Where every Id starts with EM_ and it follow with a character form A-Z and an increasing INT for every letter. I want to short the table by ID.When i do this i get the following result.
As an example an imaginary snapshot form the table will be

```
    ID |Title|Year
--------------------
EM_A1  |     |
EM_A10 |     |
EM_A2  |     |
         ***
EM_A9  |     |
         ***    
EM_C1  |     |
EM_C10 |     |
EM_C11 |     |
EM_C2  |     |
EM_C20 |     |
         ***    
EM_C9  |     |
         ***
```

---

I want to create a query that returns the table shorted with right order by ID, as an example.

```
    ID |Title|Year
--------------------
EM_A1  |     |
EM_A2  |     |
         ***
EM_A9  |     |
EM_A10 |     |
         ***    
EM_C1  |     |
EM_C2  |     |
         *** 
EM_C9  |     |
EM_C10 |     |
EM_C11 |     |
         ***  
EM_C20 |     |
         ***
```

---

Any help will be very useful.Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` to first order by letters and then by numbers following them.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6fd5/2)

```
select * from tablename
order by substring(id, 4, 1), cast(substring(id, 5) as unsigned)
```

Answer (score 1):

first part of the sub-sorting is the prefix EX_?, so I am getting LEFT 4 characters.  Secondary sort is the value AFTER it, so I am getting the value of that starting at the 5th character.

```
select *
   from 
      yourtable 
   order by 
      left( id, 4 ), 
      abs( substr( id, 5 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple query would do, try this>

```
select * from tablename ORDER By ID ASC
```